# build failed in android

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am first time using retrofit in android studio. I am facing below issue.
I also tried invalidate and restart ,clean project but problem is not resolved.
I also tried to delete the File2 but it create after running the project.
As one of the solution suggest to put below code in build.gradle but it is also not working...Please guide.

As one of the resolution suggest.

```
  packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
```

build Error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/maven/com.squareup.retrofit2/retrofit/pom.xml
    File1: E:\AndroidStudioProjects\RetrofitEx\app\libs\retrofit-2.0.1.jar
    File2: C:\Users\deepak\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.squareup.retrofit2\retrofit\2.0.1\27293c440d2085cde1d859528aff6e7d3b6ae40\retrofit-2.0.1.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

```
packagingOptions{
    pickFirst 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup.retrofit2/retrofit/pom.xml'
    pickFirst 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup.retrofit2/retrofit/pom.properties'
}
```

hope this help.